# RadCombobox SelectedValue is Null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm new to Telerik.
I have a radcombobox as below:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID ="RadCombo1" runat ="server"   
        Width="200px" autopostback ="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadCombo1_SelectedIndexChanged">   
    <Items>   
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text ="One" Value ="1"  />   
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem  Text="Two"  Value ="2" />    
    </Items>  
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

In my code I have:

```
public void RadCombo1_SelectedIndexChanged(object o, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var text1 = RadCombo1.SelectedValue;
}
```

RadCombo1.SelectedValue is null irrespective of any value selected. Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve never used Telerik, but have you tried doing it like this:

```
var text1 =RadCombo1.Items[radCombo1.SelectedIndex];
```

Comment: yes I have tried that and the selectedIndex is always -1

Comment: That’s strange because once the Selected Index changed, it shouldn’t be -1, try setting an default selected item to see the value that will appear.

Comment: below code in         protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (!IsPostBack)
            {  RadCombo1.SelectedValue = "2";}} this doesn't defaults the value to 2

Comment: e.Text and e.Value in RadCombo1_SelectedIndexChanged works

Comment: Can’t you set the default value by “RadCombo1.SelectedItem”?

Comment: The issue was I had  RadComboBox RadCombo1 = new RadComboBox() in the code..I deleted that from code and that fixed the issue..Thank you Neto Costa

Comment: Makes sense, glad you could make it.